# Modal with specific information from database, depending on where the user clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I'm developing a little something for a basketball website. I have a list of `<div>`s, each containing one player's name and photo. This data is being imported from a database using SQL/PHP. This way, each player has his own `<div>`, so to say.

What I'm having trouble with: I want a modal window to open when the user clicks on a player's `<div>`, containing more detailed information like age, last team, or stats. All this data is written in the database, so retrieving it is not a problem. But I need the information in the modal to adjust to the player name the user clicked on, i.e.: if the user clicks on Player Name A, the modal needs to contain information about Player Name A, if he clicks on Player Name B, the modal needs to contain information about Player Name B, etc.

Is there any possibility to do that? In short:

1. click on player name
2. retrieve the information about that player by his ID from the database
3. show the information in the modal

---

**Maybe I can clarify what I want to do:**

Here's the database query I'm doing for all of the five positions (PG, SG, SF, PF, C). The queries are similar to this one:

```
$sql = "SELECT Vorname, Nachname, Bildlink, ID_Spieler 
FROM spieler INNER JOIN saison20132014 
ON saison20132014.ID_Spieler = spieler.ID 
WHERE Position='PG' AND S5=1 AND Verein='".$_GET["team"]."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$name_s5_pg = $row['Vorname']."<br/><strong>".$row['Nachname']."</strong>";
$bild_s5_pg = $row['Bildlink']; 
$id_s5_pg = $row["ID_Spieler"];
```

This works fine for a simple list of the players, depending on the positions of the players. What I need to do, however, is to include the players' statistics, age, etc. in a CSS3/jQuery modal. Obviously, I only want to show the numbers of the player the user clicked on. I thought about passing the player id (e.g. `$id_s5_pg` for the PG) on to the modal, but I couldn't figure out how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jqueryUI, bootstrap, or foundation, they have good docs on their modals so i won't go into that.

You can have a title or a rel attribute to your clickable element that will contain the ID# of the element in question you are retrieving information from.

Then you have 2 options: Use the modal with ajax directly and get the formatted html via ajax or get the age, etc, what you need with a jQuery.ajax call then inject in the modal HTML (pre formatted, you can use some  tags to show data and change it dynamically using an id, i.e. , then fire the modal up in the user's UI.

Hope the above makes sense, it's 3AM, too late to build demo code right now.

Comment: The modal itself is not a problem, but I might need some guidance getting the data out of the database and into the modal.